# How to close jbpm engine and release it's resources

Tags: java, drools, jbpm

I'm now using embed jbpm 6.2 as my common service, so i write a jar which includes the jbpm service, and then i used a URL Classloader to load it, it runs pretty well, but after i closed the jbpm engine and try to remove the jars, there are some jars i can't remove.

here is the code to initialize the jbpm engine in the jar

```
    try {
        emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Constants.JBPM_JPA_UNIT_NAME);

        DBUserGroupCallbackImpl callback = new DBUserGroupCallbackImpl(props);

        RuntimeEnvironmentBuilder kBuilder = RuntimeEnvironmentBuilder.getDefault()
                .classLoader(this.getClass().getClassLoader())
                .entityManagerFactory(emf)
                .userGroupCallback(callback)
                .persistence(true);

        String path = props.getProperty(Constants.BPMN_RESOURCE_PATH);
        logger.debug("Get bpmn resource with path = {}", path);
        if (!StringUtil.isEmpty(path)) {
            String[] paths = path.split(";");
            List<File> files = getFile(paths);
            if (files != null && !files.isEmpty()) {
                List<Resource> resources = getResource(files);
                if (resources != null && !resources.isEmpty()) {
                    for (Resource resource : resources) {
                        kBuilder.addAsset(resource, ResourceType.BPMN2);
                        logger.info("Add asset to jbpm success, resource = {}", resource);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        runtimeManager = RuntimeManagerFactory.Factory.get().newSingletonRuntimeManager(kBuilder.get());

        runtime = runtimeManager.getRuntimeEngine(EmptyContext.get());

        this.kiesession = runtime.getKieSession();

        this.taskService = runtime.getTaskService();
```

here is the code to close the jbpm engine:

```
public void close() {
    if (runtimeManager != null) {
        runtimeManager.disposeRuntimeEngine(runtime);
        runtimeManager.close();
    }
    if (kiesession != null) {
        kiesession.destroy();
    }
    if (emf != null) {
        emf.close();
    }
}
```

Now i use the code like below to remove the jars:

```
jbpmService.close();
urlcloassloader.close();
System.gc();
// waiting 1min
FileUtil.forceDelete(dir)
```

Most of the jars has been removed, but i can't remove the drools-core-6.2.0.Final.jar and postgresql-42.0.0.jre7.jar, is anybody know why?

Comment: Check why these files can't be removed, permissions being the likely cause, and then remove the obstacle.

Comment: @laune tks laune, but how to check? i think maybe there exits some threads or object didn't release the resource, but i can't find it and i don't see how to do it in the doc. docs.jboss.org/jbpm/release/6.2.0.Final/jbpm-docs/html

Comment: It would be reasonable to assume that jars are in use by the JVM itself, so why should it cut off the branch on which it is sitting? Terminate the Java application and use some OS command to clean up the file space. (Although I don't quite understand why you have be so thorough. Aren't these jars going to be used during the next run?)

Comment: @laune, that's because we have developed a MicroService framework by using java, the jvm is just like a container and the business module are more like some jars, and a container can load multiple modules. So i have to clean the jars and reload the jars at backend when customer wants to update his module. But it seems the jbpm engine don't release all the jars in the jvm even though i invoke the close method.

Comment: or maybe i missed some steps when to close the engine.

Comment: Is the `FileUtil` something from your proprietary development? If so, it should tell you why `forceDelete` doesn't work. Or delete files individually to learn about errors in more detail. -- I'm afraid that your problem isn't related to the usual Drools or JBPM mechanisms.